# How to get pass "Downloading Windows support software" in Boot Camp Assistant?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, performance

I am having a problem in my Windows laptop, so I need to make a Windows 10 bootable to repair/restore it.

I am using  a Mac for making the bootable for the PC.
I downloaded the windows 10 .iso file and started bootcamp to make the bootable.
The process seems to get hanged at "Downloading Windows support software" step. 
I tried keeping it overnight, no change in the progress bar. Just stuck there at 50/60%.

Comment: Why are you using Bootcamp to fix a 'real' Windows install? Why not just get the [media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO) [page opens a different location depending on what OS you visit it with] & use that

Answer (score 1):

The problem got solved by formatting the disk.

I formatted the disk first in FAT format. Then the Boot Camp Assistant worked easily.